# Can't start product with bun

Tags: typescript, express, bun

I start with `bun`.

I have an `index.ts`:

```
import express, { Express } from "express";

const app: Express = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.json({
    massage: "hello",
    code: 200,
  });
});

app.listen(3100);
```

then i run `bun build ./src/index.ts --outdir ./build`. It build good and create `./build/index.js`.

then I run: `bun start ./build/index.js`, but i get error:

```
37481 |     return Buffer2(arg, encodingOrOffset, length);
37482 |   };
37483 |   /*! safe-buffer. MIT License. Feross Aboukhadijeh <https://feross.org/opensource> */
37484 |   var buffer = (init_buffer(), __toCommonJS(exports_buffer));
37485 |   var Buffer2 = buffer.Buffer;
37486 |   if (Buffer2.from && Buffer2.alloc && Buffer2.allocUnsafe && Buffer2.allocUnsafeSlow) {
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Buffer2.from')
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Maybe because message is written wrong?

Comment: @Stiegi what message, sir?

Comment: The key message, you wrote massage. I think message is expected there

Comment: The typo for the message key in the response in unrelated. I've only taken a brief look and it looks like a problem with how Bun transformed the code from TS to JS. From your error message you can see it attempts to read `buffer.Buffer` on L37485. `Buffer` doesn't exist on `buffer` but `buffer.default` does. Not sure why that is happening, I'd [open an issue](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/new/choose) on the Bun repo. In the meantime there are workarounds. If your environment can run Bun you can run your application in Bun instead of transforming to JS first: `bun run ./src/index.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
bun build --target=bun index.ts --outdir ./build
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what this command does and how it helps the OP.